# convert x509 ECDSA .pem cert and key to pkcs12

Tags: node.js, chilkat

Is it possible to do the same as openssl does with `chilkat` as below:

I have tried few methods with `chilkat` but when I try to use it for signing a `PDF` file it fails.

However if I do convert it with `openssl` as below it passes

```
*** ECDSA

# Generate self-signed certificate with ECDSA using two common curves
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey ec:<(openssl ecparam -name prime256v1) -keyout ecdsakey.pem -out ecdsacert.pem

# print private and public key + curve name
openssl ec -in ecdsakey.pem -text -noout

# print certificate
openssl x509 -in ecdsacert.pem -text -noout

# generate container
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ecdsakey.pem -in ecdsacert.pem -out ecdsacred.p12
```

My certificate info looks as below:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            5a:ed:46:91:6c:d6:d4:e2:89:14:47:4c:39:62:e8:80:e4:17:e9:3b
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C = IE, ST = Dublin, O = AID:Tech, OU = Blockchain, CN = ca
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 31 21:10:00 2020 GMT
            Not After : Mar 31 21:15:00 2021 GMT
        Subject: OU = client, CN = john doe
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:91:f4:62:5b:79:31:59:41:d3:ff:59:8a:41:22:
                    06:13:34:5e:ce:0a:3f:16:ea:e7:91:fe:53:4f:a3:
                    ea:63:f7:90:aa:a3:66:72:98:97:01:2a:a6:33:b7:
                    c2:97:55:bf:83:b4:ca:b4:8e:6f:95:70:1f:da:f7:
                    f5:a4:00:77:ad
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                5E:79:09:10:5D:64:BF:68:D7:29:AC:2A:BC:BB:39:2D:FF:12:D7:37
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:87:4B:D2:9C:83:32:05:97:CD:93:7A:25:B7:46:39:DF:AE:19:DE:79

            1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1: 
                {"attrs":{"hf.Affiliation":"","hf.EnrollmentID":"john doe","hf.Type":"client"}}
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:44:02:20:3c:ff:16:5f:58:c9:4b:6f:d3:7e:75:b4:68:60:
         07:a3:f7:8e:d8:0f:29:52:ee:86:8f:35:46:d0:a1:d0:f1:ea:
         02:20:47:ff:19:02:7a:58:d4:6d:e4:67:4a:ca:c4:67:54:90:
         48:8c:b0:70:29:77:97:bb:52:2f:80:7f:5a:e8:d2:0d
```

Here is `method 1` that I tried:

```
const chilkat = require('@chilkat/ck-node12-macosx');

const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs')

function chilkatExample() {

  var cert = new chilkat.Cert();
  var privKey = new chilkat.PrivateKey();

  // Load any type of certificate (.cer, .p7b, .pem, etc.) by calling LoadFromFile.
  var success = cert.LoadFromFile("static/johnDoeCert.pem");
  if (success !== true) {
      console.log(cert.LastErrorText);
      return;
  }

  // Load the private key.
  // (The various privKey methods that load from a file will automatically detect
  // the format.  It doesn't actually matter if you try to load a non-PKCS8 format private key
  // by calling LoadPkcs8EncryptedFile -- internally Chilkat will detect the format and will load
  // based on what it finds.)
  success = privKey.LoadPkcs8EncryptedFile("static/privKey.pem","");
  if (success !== true) {
      console.log(privKey.LastErrorText);
      return;
  }

  // Write the cert as PEM.
  success = cert.ExportCertPemFile("qa_output/cert.pem");

  // Or get the PEM string directly...
  console.log(cert.ExportCertPem());

  // Associate the private key with the cert object.
  success = cert.SetPrivateKey(privKey);
  if (success !== true) {
      console.log(cert.LastErrorText);
      return;
  }

  // Write the cert + private key to a .pfx file.
  success = cert.ExportToPfxFile("static/myPfx.p12","", true);
  if (success !== true) {
      console.log(cert.LastErrorText);
      return;
  }

  console.log("Success.");

}

chilkatExample();
```

And here is `method 2` that I tried:

```
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs')

try {

  const chilkat = require('@chilkat/ck-node12-macosx');

  const CERT = new chilkat.Cert();

  const encodedCert = fs.readFileSync('./static/johnDoeCert.pem', { encoding: 'base64' });
  const loadedCert = CERT.LoadFromBase64(encodedCert);

  if (!loadedCert) {
    console.log('failed to load cert')
  }

  const certChain = CERT.GetCertChain();

  if (!CERT.LastMethodSuccess){
    console.log('failed to load cert chain')
  }

  const PRIVKEY = new chilkat.PrivateKey()

  const encodedPrivKey = fs.readFileSync('./static/privKey.pem', 'utf8');
  const loadedKEy = PRIVKEY.LoadPkcs8EncryptedFile('./static/privKey.pem', "");

  if (!loadedKEy) {
    console.log('failed to load privagte key')
  }

  const PFX = new chilkat.Pfx()
  const loadedPFX = PFX.AddPrivateKey(PRIVKEY, certChain)

  if (!loadedPFX) {
    console.log('could not load PFX')
  }
  

  const writeP12 = PFX.ToFile("", "./static/johnDoe.p12")

  if (!writeP12){
    console.log('could not write PFX')
  }

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `method 1 from above works fine, my problem was on another part of my code that is not related to this.

I did slight modifications to the code above and here is my final result:

```
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs')
const chilkat = require('@chilkat/ck-node12-macosx');

try {

  const CERT = new chilkat.Cert();
  const PRIVKEY = new chilkat.PrivateKey()

  const loadedCert = CERT.LoadFromFile('./static/cert.pem');
  if (!loadedCert) {
    console.log('failed to load cert')
  }

  const loadedKEy = PRIVKEY.LoadPkcs8EncryptedFile('./static/privKey.pem', "");
  if (!loadedKEy) {
    console.log('failed to load privagte key')
  }

  // Associate the private key with the cert object.
  const associatePrivKey = CERT.SetPrivateKey(PRIVKEY);
  if (!associatePrivKey) {
      console.log(CERT.LastErrorText);
      return;
  }

  // Write the cert + private key to a .pfx file.
  const exported = CERT.ExportToPfxFile("static/cert.p12", "password", false);
  if (!exported) {
      console.log(CERT.LastErrorText);
      return;
  }

  console.log("Success.");

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```